# Ubuntu 12.04 eat a lot of internet bandwidth

Tags: 12.04, bandwidth

I don't know when this problem start to happen, but whenever I use Ubuntu on my computer, my whole house network is down. But when I switch back to windows, the whole house network is back again. Is there a problem with Ubuntu or just that my computer is eating a lot of bandwidth? Please help. Thank you

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu One?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything special in Ubuntu that eats bandwidth, at least not to that should cause the "whole house network is down".

Let's assume "whole house network is down" actually means "all the other computers can't get on the internet". This can be caused by a lot of things, and debugging is necessary. First I would confirm that it is indeed your computer that eats all the bandwidth. You could do this with nload:

Open a terminal(Ctrl-Alt-T or by menu) and install nload:

```
sudo apt-get install nload
```

Open nload:

```
nload
```

You could cycle through you interfaces(wifi, ethernet, etc) with arrow keys.

If it indeed is your computer eating bandwidth, you should check if it's inbound or outbound. Inbound could mean that an update is downloading, but a lot of outbound traffic is usually bad if your not uploading anything.

Comment: sorry, I mean that the whole network is slow down by a lot. When I use windows, other computers are still able to access to the internet easily. But when I have use Ubuntu. The internet suddenly slows down by a lot.. I will try the nload that you talk about later and will update you. Thank you

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I get connected to Wifi from my laptop with Ubuntu 12.04, other devices are getting approx. 1Mbps, however, when I disconnect then they get around 15Mbps.

Comment: Sorry for such a late comment, I have try out nload already. I realize that the internet is not eating a lot of bandwidth. However, my other device such as my brother's computer aren't still accessing to the internet very quickly